# Android RadioGroup layout

Tags: android, layout, radio-group

Hello I want to create RadioGroup that consists of 21 button, but they cant be in one line or column, there should be like 7x3. The problem is that i tried it without RadioGroup and it was fine.
I used this xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/darbu_pusl"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayJobsPage" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
    android:background="@drawable/job_btn_pi"
    android:gravity="left" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_btn_a"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

But now that i try using RadioGroup like this:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/darbu_pusl"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayJobsPage">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
    android:background="@drawable/job_btn_pi"
    android:gravity="left" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_btn_a"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

I am getting warnings that layout_alignTop and layout_toRightOf is invalid layout parameters. Can you guys help me to figure this out? Is it posible to dublicate first layout options in RadioGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `RelativeLayout` that works within a `RadioGroup`

Comment: Thanks that works just fine. I can put in a order that i wanted, but the main problems still exists I can check few buttons. Also getting waring that _"This RelativeLayout layout or its RadioGroup parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view"_ changed to this code below

Comment: `<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/darbu_pusl"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <RelativeLayout    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".DisplayJobsPage" >
` sorry for my writing style

Comment: Ok, This doesn't works. RadioGroup uses LinearLayout, which does not wrap. As radio buttons must be direct children to the radio group, you can't add sub-layouts to radio group.

Comment: so the only choice would be: `<linearlayout><radiogroup></radiogroup></linearlayout>`? is there a way then to control clicks in other radiogroups? I mean if there is a button selected in one radiogroup and then click one in another radiogroup and that one would be selected and previuos would be not. I hope you understood

Comment: No. RadioGroup is it self a LinearLayout. The only way is to use individual radio buttons and then programmically control there on/off states.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i managed to think a work around about this, that would use 3 radiogroups. It wont be the correct choice but it might work :D Thanks again.